# How to select several continue rows with interval in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select `3` rows every `5` rows. For example, the first `5` rows, I want to remain the last `3` rows.

`Input:`

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(16)})
print(df)
```

`Output:`

```
     a
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
10  10
11  11
12  12
13  13
14  14
```

`Expected:`

```
     a
2    2
3    3
4    4
7    7
8    8
9    9
12  12
13  13
14  14
```

Hopefully for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with index with floor division and get last `3` rows by [`tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html):

```
df = df.groupby(df.index // 5).tail(3)
print(df)
     a
2    2
3    3
4    4
7    7
8    8
9    9
12  12
13  13
14  14
15  15 <- last group have only one value, so tail select it
```

Another idea is get index values of each rows by `np.arange` with reshape to 2d array, select last 'columns' and flatten by `ravel`, get intersection with real index values and select by `loc`:

```
N = 5
M = 3
pos = np.arange((len(df) // N + 1) * N).reshape(-1, N)[:, -M:].ravel()
idx = np.intersect1d(df.index, pos)

df = df.loc[idx]
print(df)
     a
2    2
3    3
4    4
7    7
8    8
9    9
12  12
13  13
14  14
```

**Detail**:

```
print(np.arange((len(df) // N + 1) * N).reshape(-1, N))
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]]

print (np.arange((len(df) // N + 1) * N).reshape(-1, N)[:, -M:])
[[ 2  3  4]
 [ 7  8  9]
 [12 13 14]
 [17 18 19]]

print (np.arange((len(df) // N + 1) * N).reshape(-1, N)[:, -M:].ravel())
[ 2  3  4  7  8  9 12 13 14 17 18 19]

print(np.intersect1d(df.index, pos))
[ 2  3  4  7  8  9 12 13 14]
```